# Showing my country based on my IP, mysql optimized

Tags: php, ip

I've downloaded WIPmania's worldip table from http://www.wipmania.com/en/base/ -- the table has 3 fields and around 79k rows:

- startip // example: 3363110912
- endip // example: 3363112063
- country // example: AR (Argentina)

So, lets suppose i'm in Argentina and my IP address is: 200.117.248.17

**1)** I use this function to convert my ip to long

```
function ip_address_to_number($ip) {
    if(!$ip) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $ip = split('\.',$ip);
        return($ip[0]*16777216 + $ip[1]*65536 + $ip[2]*256 + $ip[3]);
    }
}
```

**2)** I search for the proper country code by matching the long converted ip:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM worldip WHERE '.ip_address_to_number($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).' BETWEEN startip AND endip';
```

which is equivalent to:
**SELECT country FROM worldip WHERE 3363174417 BETWEEN startip AND endip** (benchmark: Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.2109 sec))

## Now comes the *real* **question**.

What if another bunch of argentinian guys also open the website and they all have these ip addresses:

- 200.117.248.17
- 200.117.233.10
- 200.117.241.88
- 200.117.159.24

Since i'm caching all the sql queries; instead of matching EACH of the ip queries in the database, would it be better (and right) just to match the 2 first sections of the ip by modifying the function like this?

```
function ip_address_to_number($ip) {
    if(!$ip) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $ip = split('\.',$ip);
        return($ip[0]*16777216 + $ip[1]*65536);
    }
}
```

(notice that the 3rd and 4th splitted values of the IP have been removed).

That way instead of querying these 4 values:

- 3363174417
- 3363170570
- 3363172696
- 3363151640

...all i have to query is: 3363110912 (which is 200.117.**0.0** converted to long).

Is this right? any other ideas to optimize this process?

Comment: If you just throw an index on the worldip column, queries should be lightning fast.   I bet queries will complete in under 10 ms.  Benchmark what you have, once the index is in place.  If you haven't already benchmarked, you're optimizing prematurely.

Comment: @Srinivas: i can get those with getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'); -- just didnt add it to this code yet.


@Frank: the thing is that this website has around 3 million visits per month. i cannot benchmark that amount of queries until this code goes live -- that is why i have to optimize prematurely ;) -- i'll add an index though: PRIMARY start end

Comment: I've added benchmark data for 1 query: Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.2109 sec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you absolutely have to use WIPmania? if not, Maxmind offers an open source solution: http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry. The advantage is that it's a binary file, and there's a PHP extension (you'd have to compile it ans install it). Used it on a couple of projects, the lookups are blazing fast. You can get the PCL extension here:
http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip

Comment: wow, nice alternative. that means no mysql connections at all right?

Comment: Yes it doesn't rely on mysql at all, runs completely standalone once installed...

Answer (score 2):

No.

`193.150.1.1` - russian IP
`193.150.230.1` - swedish IP

You possibly could truncate it to first three octects, but... you wouldn't have that many cache hits. And it's very likely that some /24 network is divided between two contries. Sometimes, blocks smaller than /24 are given out.