# How to store ip2long negative value on a 32 bit system to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ip2long

I have to store an IP address into a MySQL table running on a 32 bit system.

On a 64 bit system I would simply use `INT(10) UNSIGNED` since `ip2long` will always be an absolute value.

How to make it work on 32 bit? I have two options.

1. Remove `UNSIGNED` and store negative values, but I'm not sure if
   there is still a chance of values being too large or too small once
   this is done (because the upper limit will be decreased by half to
   allow for the lower limit to be negative)
2. Use `sprintf("%u",ip2long( $ip ))` [checkout this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062843/php-ip2long-returning-negative-val) (will be probably slower than 1.)

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert IP not in PHP but in SQL insert query using INET_ATON function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton. You need to use INT UNSIGNED as your column type.

Comment: I would certainly *strongly* recommend using the underlying database to convert string representations to numbers - it simplifies a lot of the query processing. You can use BIGINT instead of UNSIGNED INT, or even consider using BINARY(16) to accomodate IPV6

Comment: `INET_ATON` is definitely the recommended way if you write plain SQL, but what if you have to use a database wrapper e.g. WordPress database class to insert an IP? You write plain SQL or use PHP instead.